# Setting up auth gateway using AWS ELB and SpringBoot

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, spring-boot, amazon-elb

Working on a jwt based authentication microservice using SpringBoot. It checks incoming request with valid `jwt` token. Want to use it as an auth gateway for rest of the services in the system.

How can I change ELB configuration in a way that it redirects all the requests to auth gateway? 
ELB would also need to provide original url so that after the validation auth service can redirect the request to intended rest endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

ELB doesn't support this functionality.  Instead, have your ELB direct traffic to the gateway, then the gateway can check for the `jwt` and if its valid you can allow the request to proceed to the backend services.  If its invalid, then handle that behavior as well (e.g. redirect to login page).

Comment: How would gateway know where to redirect the request to?